# Table not found with H2

Tags: jpa, wildfly, h2

My Java EE application cannot find tables. I am using WildFly (as the application server) and H2 (as the DB, in the embedded mode).

The error is:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "MY_TABLE" not found
```

Look at my table creation:

```sql
create table "MY_TABLE" (
    -- ...
);
```

See how my entity is defined:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyTable {
    // ...
}
```

This is how I call JPA (this causes the exception):

```java
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

// ...

entityManager.find(MyTable.class, 1);
```

My *persistence.xml* is:

```xml
<persistence-unit name="myapp" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/myappDS</jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
```

And the *standalone.xml* in my WildFly:

```xml
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myappDS" pool-name="myappDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:~/myapp;SCHEMA=PUBLIC</connection-url>
    <driver>h2</driver>
</datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
```

Everything looks good so why the exception? Do I need to flush something? Or set schema somewhere?

If I configure another datasource (having the same DB structure) in WildFly (for example Postgres), everything works fine. That would mean that the datasource configuration is the place causing the error.

(Yes, I am totally sure the DB is not empty and the connection URL is correct as I have tried it from an SQL client.)

Comment: Why don't you configure the <user-name/> and <password/> elements under <security/>? Maybe Wildfly connects with the wrong credentials?

Comment: I have tried and it didn't help. (In addition, empty user and password are used.)

Comment: Have you tried to use an absolute path instead of `~/myapp`?

Comment: Yes, with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the application as a different user than you are testing to connect with? In that case the the `~` in the connection path will resolve to different home folders, and thus different databases.

Otherwise I would suggest connecting with the Shell in the h2 jar file and run `show tables` to verify that the table exists and with the correct casing. Start the shell by running:

```
java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Shell
```

Comment: I am running it all under same user. As I replied above, even with absolute path it gives the same result. I can try to run the shell but with the actual setup, `SHOW TABLES` returned me empty list.

Comment: OK, I have tried the shell. It normally returns my tables. So I don't know what is wrong with my datasource.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with WildFly, but there should be an admin console. Try see if you can find the datasource there and check that it is correctly configured. Or enable debug logging and see if you can check what URL it uses for the connection. Something is fishy here, and my guess is that the application is somehow connecting on a different URL...

Comment: Also, if you start the shell leaving it open, and then start the application, the application _should_ fail with a "Database may be already in use" sql exception. If it doesn't you _know_ that you are connecting on a different URL...

Answer (score 0):

Where do you store your script for the table creation? Is it in classpath of the application?

In my test setup I let hibernate generate the tables on startup (and dropping it on shutdown) and using an `import.sql` script for the test-data generation, which is in the folder `src/main/resources`.

```
<persistence-unit name="myapp" transaction-type="JTA">
  <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/myappDS</jta-data-source>
  <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: The script is outside of the classpath. I created the tables from an SQL client (the same connection string, the same user). I don't want to let JPA/Hibernate to change the structure.

Comment: Your comment on the other answer is: **I can try to run the shell but with the actual setup, `SHOW TABLES` returned me empty list.**
Then the table does not exist. Make sure you create the tables correctly and `SHOW TABLES` gives you the correct result.

Comment: You didn't understand. I tried `SHOW TABLES` in my application - no tables were found. When I tried the same command from the shell, my tables were returned.